# MYSQL Communications link failure with Docker compose Spring Boot Config Server

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

My book-service unable to connect mysql-server in docker compose. Check below log.
It was working one day ago, but today its not working, even I have not touched single line of code.
This is my docker file, book-service property file and Log traces.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  MYSQL-SERVER:
    image: mysql
    container_name: MYSQL-SERVER
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./docker:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
  config-server:
    container_name: config-server
    build:
      context: config-server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: demo/config-server-service:latest
    depends_on:
      - MYSQL-SERVER
    environment:
      - spring.profiles.active=native
      - spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=config-store
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
  eureka-server:
    container_name: eureka-server
    build:
      context: eureka-server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: demo/eureka-server-service:latest
    environment:
      - spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config-server:8888
    depends_on:
      - config-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
  book-service:
    container_name: book-service
    build:
      context: book-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: demo/book-service:latest
    environment:
      - db.host=MYSQL-SERVER
      - db.port=3306
      - db.name=demo_book_schema
      - db.username=root
      - db.password=root
      - EUREKA_HOST_URL=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config-server:8888
      - logging.level.=DEBUG
    depends_on:
      - config-server
      - eureka-server
      - MYSQL-SERVER
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8011:8011
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
volumes:
  database:
    driver: local
networks:
  spring-cloud-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Property File book-service:

```
app.version=1.0
db.host=localhost
db.port=3306
db.name=demo_book_schema
db.username=root
db.password=root
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.name}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=${db.username}
spring.datasource.password=${db.password}

#Hibernates Properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.flyway.schemas=${db.name}
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration


eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_HOST_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
eureka.client.registerWithEureka = true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry = true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=1
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=2
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
eureka.client.lease.duration=5
logging.level.com.kapilsony.userservice.logging=DEBUG
```

Logs:-

> . ____ _ __ _ _
>
> /\ / _**'* __ _ *(*)* __ __ _ \ \ \ \
>
> ( ( )___ | '_ | '*| | '* / _` | \ \ \ \
>
> \/ __*)| |*)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )
>
> ' |__**| .__|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
>
> =========|*|==============|*__/=/*/*/_/
>
> :: Spring Boot :: (v2.5.1)
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:50.999 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server
> at : http://config-server:8888
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:51.244 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment:
> name=book-service, profiles=[default], label=session2, version=null,
> state=null
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:51.247 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source:
> [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'},
> BootstrapPropertySource
> {name='bootstrapProperties-file:config-store/book-service.properties'}]
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:51.278 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> c.k.bookservice.BookserviceApplication : No active profile set,
> falling back to default profiles: default
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:53.239 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data
> JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:53.602 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data
> repository scanning in 349 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:54.257 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope : BeanFactory
> id=7c3a88a8-133e-3e51-9c38-54b1877995f3
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:55.713 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with
> port(s): 8021 (http)
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:55.841 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext:
> initialization completed in 4516 ms
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:56.609 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter : Flyway Community Edition
> 7.10.0 by Redgate
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:56.643 INFO 1 --- [ main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:57.888 ERROR 1 --- [ main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during
> pool initialization.
>
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
> link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
>
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
>
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
>
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
>
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
>
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
>
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
>
> at
> org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:55)
> [flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
>
> at
> org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:68)
> [flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
>
> at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:510)
> [flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
>
> at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:170)
> [flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
> [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> [spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
>
> at
> com.kapilsony.bookservice.BookserviceApplication.main(BookserviceApplication.java:23)
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
> ~[bookservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
> ~[bookservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
> ~[bookservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> ~[bookservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException:
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> ... 43 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
> refused)
>
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> at
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
>
> ... 46 common frames omitted
>
> 2021-07-31 20:27:57.893 WARN 1 --- [ main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
>
> Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>
> ---
>
> SQL State : 08S01
>
> Error Code : 0
>
> Message : Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

I'm providing proper DataSource Properties using docker environment:-

```
db.host=MYSQL-SERVER
db.port=3306
db.name=demo_book_schema
db.username=root
db.password=root
```

Comment: I am able to ping from book-service docker instance to mysql-server instance using below command, Its successfully pinging mysql-server.
ping MYSQL-SERVER

Comment: @in4976 , check again its not same. Please check my configuration everything is correct. I'm providing proper database url ie. correct docker container host-name.

Comment: @docker : look into the matter.